# irrational conformal dimension

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, scaling

I know examples of Conformal Field Theories in which the scaling dimension of certain operators is an integer number or a fractional number.
However I do not know any example in which the scaling dimension is irrational.

Do such theories exist, or are they forbidden for some reason?

Comment: It's not possible in rational conformal field theories (i.e. with a finite number of primary fields), due to Vafa's theorem. There are irrational CFTs, such as Liouville field theory.

Comment: @MengCheng forgive me if my question is stupid.
The "irrational" in the name "irrational CFT" means that the scaling dimensions are irrational?

Furthermore, if I understand correctly these class of CFT are in 2d (at least Liouville theory is). Are there examples of irrational scaling dimensions in 4d?

Comment: @FedericoCarta, rational CFT is a CFT with a finite number of primaries of the full symmetry group (i.e. Virasoro, affine, etc). Irrational CFT is a CFT with an infinite number of such primaries.

Comment: @FedericoCarta These are all 1+1d CFTs. The conformal symmetry is so powerful in 1+1 that we can almost completely understand the properties of CFTs. In higher dimensions, even 2+1, as far as I know the situation is much less clear. Except for free bosons/fermions, I think very few CFTs are really understood (i.e. we do not know the exact values of scaling dimensions, only approximate ones or numerical values). Perhaps theories with a high degree of supersymmetry yield better analytical results.